# Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 502 response code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, zappa

trying to simple zappa app built with Flask, but after `zappa deploy dev` I get the following error :

**Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 502 response code.**

▼ Struct

```
.
├── app
│   ├── env
│   └── main.py
└── zappa_settings.json
```

▼ app/main.py

```py
#main.py
import sys
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, jsonify, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
     return 'hello zappa!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
 if len(sys.argv) > 1:
     app.debug = True
     app.jinja_env.auto_reload = True
     app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000)
 else:
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

▼ zappa_settings.json

```js
{
    "dev": {
        "app_function": "app.main",
        "profile_name": null,
        "project_name": "app",
        "runtime": "python3.8",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-kgikw9e6r"
    }
}
```

▼ zappa tail

```
[1644312001414] [ERROR] TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.app'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 657, in lambda_handler
    return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 251, in lambda_handler
    handler = cls()
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.app_module = importlib.import_module(self.settings.APP_MODULE)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 122, in import_module
    raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
```

- Zappa version used: 0.54.1
- Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8

Anyone here to help?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this hope this works for you although I haven't used zappa before but I don't see any issue with your config file.

```
#main.py
import sys
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, jsonify, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
     return 'hello zappa!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
         app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000, debug='True')
    else:
         app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! but I guess there was problem in json file. so It was solved by moving josn file to app folder and changing it to "app_function": "main.app". Thank you again for your answer ! :)